# Align ipywidget button to center

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I´m looking to align to the center a button object from the ipywidget function. Here´s a sample of the code I´m using

```
bt = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='180px'),style = 
    {'description_width': '25%'})
b_config_save = widgets.Button(
    description="Save",
    layout=bt.layout,
    style=bt.style,
    button_style='primary'
)
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a [flexbox](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-Flexbox-layout) layout as shown below.

```
btn = widgets.Button(description="Save")
box_layout = widgets.Layout(display='flex',
                flex_flow='column',
                align_items='center',
                width='50%')
box = widgets.HBox(children=[btn],layout=box_layout)
display(box)
```

Comment: Doc has moved, link doesn't point there anymore. [New link](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Layout.html?#The-Flexbox-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use table ,maybe you can find some help [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1849)